# Specific md5 hashing scheme in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, hash, md5

I have looked for an answer in an existing question, but found nothing which covers this hashing scheme in Rails.

I am currently migrating a PHP project over to Ruby-on-Rails, which I am still learning. I am struggling to port over an MD5 (I know, it's only temporary...) hashing scheme for hashing user passwords. I have plain MD5 working, but cannot find the correct syntax for the hashing scheme I need.

The mechanics of the hashing scheme in the PHP project are:

Create MD5 hash of password.
Create MD5 hash of salt.
Concatenate password_hash with salt_hash.
Create MD5 hash of concatenated_string.
Compare stored_hash to concatenated_string

The PHP for the hash creation is:

```
function fn_generate_salted_password($password, $salt)
{
    $_pass = '';

    if (empty($salt)) {
        $_pass = md5($password);
    } else {
        $_pass = md5(md5($password) . md5($salt));
    }

    return $_pass;
}
```

The (pathetic) attempt I have for this section in Rails so far is:

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
  def valid_password?(password)
    if self.salt.present
      if ::Digest::MD5.hexdigest((::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)).(::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(salt))) == self.stored_hash
        *# Do some stuff*
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to strive towards is killing off MD5 passwords as quickly as possible. Remember, when someone logs in and you verify their password as correct you have an opportunity to update their user record with a properly hashed (e.g. bcrypt) version of same, no need to harass the user to change their password.

Comment: To help people with your problem can you given an example of how a password like "testing" or "example" is saved so others can verify your code is working correctly?

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that once they are authenticated and logged in, the MD5 hash is removed from the database and the password is hashed in bcrypt etc.

I will check on what the final hashed results are for "testing" and "example" in the PHP application and update this question with the answer as soon as I can.

Just to add, the "salt" that I need to target here would have a field name in the database of legacy_salt, not "salt". Would I need to define this somewhere as it is not the default "salt" used by digest for MD5?

Comment: If this was done properly, and I'm using the term very loosely here since this style of hashing was obsolete in the early 1990s, then the salt would be some random value stored in a separate field.

Comment: Hi tadman, yes, that is the case. The salt in this instance is a random value stored in a seperate field, which is unique to each user. I know that MD5 is terrible, but it was what I inherited. I am eager to rid the new application of MD5 as quickly as possible!

Comment: Good luck slaying this dragon. Your users will appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks tadman. The alternative is a mass password-reset mailout, which I would LOVE to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  secret = if salt.present?
             [password, salt].map { |part| ::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(part) }.join
           else
             password
           end

 stored_hash == ::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret)
end
```

Comment: This can be extended to recognize newer-format hashes like `"$2a$10$...."` and handle it with Bcrypt as well.